# How do I set the target platform for an ASP.NET Website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, web

I have a website project that needs to load a 32 bit DLL, and I am developing the site on Windows 7 64 bit.

Because of this, one of the 32 bit dlls is failing to load.

Normally in a desktop application project I can go to project settings, however I am unable to locate the setting.

I am using Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My idea is that it introduces nothing valuable.

Even if you are allowed to compile in 32 bit mode, anyone else can configure it to be run in 64 bit application pool mistakenly. That can be a disaster still.

As application pool bitness is always an IIS setting, we should only be careful about the site deployment, not compilation.

Comment: Then how do I change it in IIS? I have looked there too. I assumed it would have been a web.config, but if it's in IIS, changing it there would be just fine too.

Comment: That relies on which version of Windows you use. For Windows Vista/Server 2008/7/Server 2008 R2, you can check that in IIS Manager by enabling "32 bit application" in Advanced Settings for an application pool.

For Windows Server 2003, you need to use a command line,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/895976

Comment: @Lex Li - I found this thread because I have the same question...just looked at the KB entry 895976 but I see nothing there about the "command line" needed. Also, please confirm that if this were a "web application project" (rather than a "web site project"), the search for the IIS setting would not be necessary because a "web application project" exposes the Platform target dropdown in the Project Properties.

Comment: Sounds like you are not familiar with IIS. The full command line can be found here,

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0aafb9a0-1b1c-4a39-ac9a-994adc902485.mspx?mfr=true